# Additionally factor like 0.33 mail after enable to display time in linemode

Tags: time-date

I enabled time-show on the line-mode following the instruction of [EmacsWiki: Display Time](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DisplayTime)

```
(display-time-mode 1)
```

The single line was appended and it take effects but has side outputs

Additionally displayed factor 0.33 and mail.

What does the factor of 0.33 guide to do, it should not be there is 0.33 piece of mail to check.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the load-average and mail indicators. You can turn them off by customizing stuff in the `display-time` customize group.

Comment: get it. it indicate that there exist mails to check and the average load factor.